# Writing Several Strings into a CSV File in Python

Tags: python, csv, file-io

So I've created Python code that scrapes several different websites and then does some things with the lists created. I know how to turn a list into a string and how to then write a csv file from the string. My question is, can I write several strings into the same csv file and put each in its own row with a unique header? The code below will get all the data into the csv file, but not in its own rows.

```
str1 = "\n".join(data1)
str2 = "\n".join(data2)
str3 = "\n".join(matches)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now_str = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
outfilename = 'data-{}.csv'.format(now_str)
outpath = 'data/'
outFile = open(outfilename, 'write')
outFile.write(str1)
outfile.write(str2)
outfile.write(str3)
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Is one CSV file the best format for this?

Comment: For someone to answer your question, they will need to know what `data1`, `data2`, and `matches` are, or what output you are now getting.

Comment: Thanks, @Paul. data1 and data2 are lists of binomial scientific names. Matches is a list of binomial scientific names that are common to both data1 and data2. This is a daily scraping report that I'd like to be able to store in a single csv file each day.

Comment: Python has a builtin module, conveniently named [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), which is designed to make reading and writing csv files straightforward.

Comment: SoI've heard (re: Python csv module). Guess I need to read up. Thanks.

Comment: So using the csv module is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is **no**, you should probably not create a CSV with multiple sections, each with independent headers.

There is no gold standard that defines the CSV file format, though [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) might come close.  So while you are technically free to create your own extensions and call it a CSV file (such as multiple independent subfiles with their own headers, as you propose) this is extremely uncommon among CSVs.  I predict it would give undesirable results in most software if you attempted to read such a file.

Best practice would be to create one CSV per dataset if the datasets have different schema.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. As you may have intuited, I'm a bit of a noob, but I'm learning. So you're saying to go ahead and write a separate csv for each scraped dataset each day? The datasets are all the same schema (if I'm interpreting schema) correctly. They are all binomial scientific names.

Comment: When you said "unique header", I took this to mean each header was different. That means the column names or types or number of columns are different and, thus, it's a different schema.

If all the data really do share the same column headers then go ahead and write a single CSV file and just stick a single header on the first line.  That would be a well-constructed CSV file.

Good luck.  If my answer satisfies you, please mark it as "answered", above.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm sorry for any confusion. I do need to break the data sets out into separate columns representing the different websites from which the data was scraped, so I may just go ahead and do as you suggested and have each dataset be its own csv file.

Comment: Sounds like the right thing to do.  The nice thing about constructing valid CSV files is even if you end up with a large collection of them, it's a file format any spreadsheet and many other programs can read and write so you can always read them or merge them later with common or free tools. Good luck.